# disable submit button until file selected for upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, webforms

I have a form for uploading images. I'd like to disable the submit button, until user selects an image to upload. I'd like to do it with jQuery. Currently I have a JavaScript function that prevent user from submitting the form more than once by disabling it on submit. It'd be nice to combine this functionality with the new one.

Here's what I've got now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitonce(theform) {
    //if IE 4+ or NS 6+
    if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
        //screen thru every element in the form, and hunt down "submit" and "reset"
        for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
            var tempobj = theform.elements[i]
            if (tempobj.type.toLowerCase() == "submit" || tempobj.type.toLowerCase() == "reset")
            //disable em
            tempobj.disabled = true
        }
    }
}
</script>
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" onSubmit="submitonce(this)">
 <input type="file" name="my_field" value="" />
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The following seems to work reliably in Chrome and Firefox (Ubuntu 10.10), I'm unable to check on other platforms at the moment:

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                    // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
                    // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                } 
            }
            );
    });
```

#### html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E42XA/).

Comment: Thanks, I like the simplicity of this solution. How can it be modified to disable submit button again once the form is submitted?

Comment: OK, got it. I've added the following function: $("#uploadForm").submit(function(){
     $("input[type=submit]", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
 });

Comment: I believe it would be better if you wrote the condition in this manner:
$('.upload-pm-btn').attr('disabled', !$(this).val());

That way when you later on delete the value from the file upload, the button gets disabled again.

Comment: Bug: If you unselect files, the button keeps active!

Answer (score 19):

Slightly simpler way using prop() which I think is the preferred way to do it now:

```
$('input:file').on("change", function() {
    $('input:submit').prop('disabled', !$(this).val()); 
});
```

Tested in IE, Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: This works fine, since it gets the button `disabled` if one unselects the file(s)

Comment: This looks (to my admittedly jQuery-challenged eye) like it would disable all submit buttons on a given form that has an empty file upload control? Fine in the OP's example but it might be worth mentioning what is needed if there are multiple submits or multiple file upload controls?

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is looking at this now (in 2021), this is the non-jquery solution I was able to come up with!! Some of this won't work with older browsers, so your mileage might vary- but if you're looking for a modern simple solution- this should be more than fine.

```html
<div>
  <form method="post" action="someAction" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileUploaded" />
    <input type="submit" disabled="true" />
  </form>
  <script>
    document.querySelector("input[type=file]").onchange = ({
      target: { value },
    }) => {
      document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").disabled = !value;
    };
  </script>
</div>
```

Some notes about this solution: `onChange` takes a function that returns an object `event`, which has `target` and in there `value`. `value` is the string of the file name uploaded, and returns empty string when a user cancels the selection.

---

If you're looking for a solution that works with multiple file inputs and submissions, you can use class names to grab the right one.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<div>
  <form
    method="post"
    action="someAction"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
  >
    <input class="fileUpload1" type="file" name="fileUploaded" />
    <input class="fileUpload1" type="submit" disabled="true" />
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form
    method="post"
    action="someOtherAction"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
  >
    <input class="fileUpload2" type="file" name="fileUploaded2" />
    <input class="fileUpload2" type="submit" disabled="true" />
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
// script.js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]").forEach(
  (fileInput) =>
    (fileInput.onchange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
      document.querySelector(
        `input[type=submit].${fileInput.className}`
      ).disabled = !value;
    })
  );
```

Comment: This is useful—though it's worth acknowledging that the original question explicitly asks for jQuery, and thus this answers a question that wasn't asked.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that the question description asks for "I'd like to do it in jQuery"... However, it's not explicitly clear if the usage of jQuery is necessary, or if it's being asked naively- assuming that a pure js solution wouldn't be elegant. Hopefully this example shows that pure js solution can be achieved, and (because it's still JavaScript) is fully compatible with jQuery library in use. Furthermore, unlike the selected solution, this one correctly disables the button again if the selection is cancelled.

Comment: I think it's also important to note that the original question was asked over a decade ago, but since this is one of the top Google results for disabling a form button in JavaScript, hopefully this helps people looking for a solution even if you are correct that it's not exactly fitting 

Comment: The JS as given wasn't working for me.  After a few minutes' troubleshooting I found the difficulty:  it targets an `input` element, but my form uses a `button` element for its submit.  I tweaked the JS accordingly and it works perfectly.

Comment: document.querySelector("button[type=submit]").disabled = !value;

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
   $('#my_uploader').change(function() {
      if($(this).val()) {
        $('#my_submit_button').attr('disabled', '');
      } else {
        $('#my_submit_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    });
```

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is, properly, a Boolean; I'd recommend using `.attr('disabled',true')` / `.attr('disabled',false)`.

Comment: you should use .removeAttr("disabled")

Comment: That's such an obvious point, @hunter, I'm **ashamed** that it had never occurred to me before you pointed out (sincerely, I'm not (to my shame) being facetious)... =/ +1

Comment: In HTML boolean attributes such as disabled and readonly can only legally take the name of the attribute.
eg. disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly"
Most browsers however accept any value for the attribute as being in the affimative.
So the following are equivalent:
disabled="disabled"
disabled
disabled="true"
disabled="no"

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-boolean_attribute-1

Answer (score 4):

instead of using script simply use required in input field

Answer (score 1):

If you're a fan of ternary expressions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $submit = $('#submit_document');
    var $file = $('#file_path');

    $file.change(
        function(){
            $submit.attr('disabled',($(this).val() ? false : true));
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the submit, is it potentially more helpful to offer instruction if the user presses it without selecting a file first? So add something like this as the onclick code of the submit?

```
var bFileEmpty = !document.getElementById('filControl').value; if (bFileEmpty) alert('Please select a file'); return !bFileEmpty;
```

Note that your file control will need an ID as well as a name