# Disable submit button when file is not selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable a submit button when a file is not selected following a working solution online. Is it something to do with the script type?

This is the example I followed: [disable submit button until file selected for upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056336/disable-submit-button-until-file-selected-for-upload)

```
<html>
        <head>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
            $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()){
                    $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                }
                else {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                }
            });
    });
        </script>
</head>

<body>
   <form action="#" method="post">

            <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />


       </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: Your code works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/fUvvb/. You aren't including the jQuery library here however

Comment: Hi, what is actually happening when you select a file? Do you want the button to enable only when the button is pressed or when a file is truely selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with Jquery declared because the Jquery is not included:

```
  <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 


            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            $('input:file').change(
                function(){
                    if ($(this).val()){
                        $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                    }
                    else {
                        $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                    }
                });
        });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <form action="#" method="post">

                <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />


           </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried editing the src, but it's still not working. Could it be something else? But it's weird. It's working on Jsfiddle.net

Comment: Excuse me, on my pc function and you want do you do after the submit??
The script needs the connection's Internet for using Jquery.
Otherwise, copy http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js , paste on Words or Block notes and save on the pc for use without Internet

Comment: Hi, thanks again. What i want to do is to enable the button after i have chosen a file. When no file is selected, it should be disable. Currently it's disabled initially, but after a file is selected, it's still disable. 
What you're trying to say is that if i want to use jquery, i need connection to internet?
Sorry,i'm quite new in this.

Comment: Welcome... The script  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script> need the internet 's connection because this is a link with web.
Then for use without the connection, you copy the text on http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js , paste in editor and save in ´jquery-2.0.0.min.js´
After you have to change the script (then replace) with  ´<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>´
if you want more details or clarification add me with mrk1989@hotmail.it on Skype or messenger

Comment: Hi, i have email you and added you in skype. Let me know when you're free. Thanks alot Mirko.

Answer (score 0):

Include the jQuery library in the `<head>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I've edit the javascript part. However, it's still not working.