# Disabling Submit Button when no file selected during php upload

Tags: php, jquery, html, upload

[I tried to follow this code - confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056336/disable-submit-button-until-file-selected-for-upload)

Here is my code for my upload. I am not exactly sure where/how to include the jquery code to enable the button after file is selected. I tried just copying the example and testing that but I still couldn't get it to work.

HTML

```
<div id="floatLeft">   
<label for="fileToUpload">Select CSV file to Upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>
<div id="floatRight">
<input type="submit" value="Generate" name="submit" disabled />

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('input:file').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
                // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
            } 
        }
        );
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery? Because it works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3x1kLhkm/

Comment: What's the version of your jquery?

Comment: I have it in the root directory of my server. Calling it with <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min">. Also had it include folder and tried calling it there. Tried putting script in <head> and also in <body>. Still not working for some reason

Comment: Maybe it's the version of your jquery. Try changing this part ` $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);` to ` $('input:submit').prop('disabled',false);` Maybe it's' the version of your jquery. Your script must be above the closing tag of your body.

Comment: Tried changing it and getting same result.

Comment: Go to the developers tab see if your jquery is running.

Comment: @AmarokVII Can i see the print screen of your text editor which has the `scripts` tags ?

Comment: Are you missing .js from the script src?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work. Make sure that you have :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

within your head tags and that your JQuery is within script tags.

Comment: I added it locally from my server. `<script src="include/jquery-1.11.3.min"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers look goop for smaller file uploads, since `.change` will be fired without waiting the end of upload.

For asynchronous uploads, https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ is very useful.

This piece of code from the Drupal world do the job:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
if(typeof settings.extraData != 'undefined' && typeof settings.extraData.view_display_id != 'undefined') {

    switch(settings.extraData.view_display_id){

        case "your_view_id":

            console.log('your_view_id ajax results!');

            break;

        default:

            console.log('some other ajax result...');

            break;

    }
}
```

});