# Web Forms: Enable button once file is selected

Tags: jquery, webforms

Using Javascript or Jquery, I'd like to enable the upload button once a file is selected.

Here's my markup:

```
<input ID="FileUploadControl" type="file" name="fileInput" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload Image" onclick="UploadButton_Click" disabled />
```

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FileUploadControl').on("change", function () {
            $('#UploadButton').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
        });
    });
```

The button is disabled, but I can't seem to get it enabled.

I've also tried methods mentioned here but it won't work for some reason:
[disable submit button until file selected for upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056336/disable-submit-button-until-file-selected-for-upload)

I have to use `<asp:Button>` because `<input type=submit>` doesn't work.

Other submit button that I've tried:

```
<input type="submit" id="UploadButton" value="Upload Image" runat="server" onclick="UploadButton_Click"/>
```

Currently using in `<head></head>`: jquery-2.2.3.min.js

Comment: If you are requiring a file to be uploaded, why aren't you using the a FileUpload control? That would then permit you to use a RequiredFieldValidator to assure that a file is actually sent even if someone forces postback. As it is, someone could re-enable the button and click it whether they attach a file or not.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, this is good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want enable button, you need to **`remove attr disabled`** rather than set `disabled=false`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FileUploadControl').on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val(),
      btn = $('#UploadButton');
    val ? btn.removeAttr("disabled") : btn.attr("disabled");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="file" id="FileUploadControl" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="UploadButton" disabled>
</form>
```